# Changes in base.html

Tags: python, django, templates, radix

I was making some changes in my template/base.html and uploaded in my FTP server and changes I've made are not showing up.
What I can do ?

Reload the server are not a option. =/

ps. I have ssh access to the server in a normal account.

Thanks !!

Comment: some its uses from the cache. If you can try to clear cache.

Comment: show us how are you sending your base.html to ftp.

Comment: Since we don't have visibility on your code: did your changes involve loading images, css-files or javascript files? You might need to do a [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) in those cases...

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily need to reload the server, but why is it not an option? You will need to do it if you make changes to Python code, anyway.

Comment: @ShafikurRahman I'm not use cache and changes are not visible even if I open in incognito tab or clean my browser cache.

Comment: @Ahtisham what did you mean, "how sending to ftp"?
I'm sending using FileZilla.

Comment: @lodb
I only create a function in js and add just a few onclick in anchor tag. 
It not involve external files like js, images etc.

Comment: did you ran `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: @Ahtisham
No, I just made the changes and replace the file.
I supposed the changes would come.

Comment: Ok. Look at@Agostinho comment. Its may works.

Comment: Guys almost 24 hrs later the changes are showing up. 
I don't know how to explain that.

Can it be a scheduled reload of the server?